# Folder of images to individual PDF reports

Tags: python, html, image, pdf-generation

I have various folders containing images. Inside each folder the size of the images are the same, but the sizes vary slightly between the various folders.

I am trying to automate processing the folders by taking each image and placing it within a Letter template file (existing PDF file) then saving it before moving to the next image in the folder. The template file is just a simple header and footer document.

I have thought about using python to replace the image within a HTML file or as an overlay in the exiting PDF template, but not sure if my approach is correct or if there is a more simpler option.

I have already looked at:

- pdfkit
- wkhtmltopdf
- ReportLab

Just looking for some suggestions at this point.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. Have you attempted an implementation using any of the listed libraries and did you run into problems? A request for library suggestions may be better suited for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com